# remove BeautifulSoup tags from Text file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, text-files

I have `bs4` installed. How do you remove HTML tags from a textfile? In a nutshell, I have a script that writes ESRI metadata items to a textfile from that metadata's HTML page, and for a couple of these items the HTML format code is also written for some reason. How can I use BeautifulSoup to remove this code? It looks sloppy.

The Description item of this attachment has the HTML: [Textfile](http://www.willcogis.org/website2014/gis/Data/Precincts%20Metadata.txt)

Comment: what is the expected output, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Try `soup.text`

Comment: do you want to extract that data without html tags ?

Comment: @johnII the expected output is a textfile with no HTML code infused in the text.

Comment: @t.m.adam thanks, yes I've made a note of that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the [`w3lib` library](https://github.com/scrapy/w3lib) for this, no need of `bs4`:

```
from w3lib.html import remove_tags

text = "your text"
new_text = remove_tags(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

@eLRuLL Thanks, that works great to remove the tags. However, some of these metadata descriptions I will be using this script for are pretty lengthy and entering the text as a variable seems like a bad idea. For that reason, I tried this:

```
import arcpy
import arcpy_metadata as md
from w3lib.html import remove_tags
ws = r'Database Connections\ims to Plainfield.sde\gisedit.DBO.Tax_Map_LY\gisedit.DBO.Tax_Map_Parcels_LY'
metadata = md.MetadataEditor(ws)
def meta2txt():
    abstract = metadata.abstract
    if abstract:
        w3lib.html.remove_tags(abstract)
```

The script runs but the HTML is still there.